# How to use TCP protocol with headers

Tags: c, tcp, data-protection

I am writing a small module where I send 4k blocks from one machine to another for replication. The blocks contain both data blocks and meta data blocks. Since we write on the TCP socket flat data, how do I understand on the target machine that the block I am getting is a metadata block or a data block?

I am assuming I need to use some headers to do so. Can I do it in rpc gen? If yes does anyone have an example?

Ive looked at NDMP protocol and it has some stuff I need, however, me using it would mean completely changing the usage of NDMP protocol. Is there any protocol/way to do this?

So I am expecting something like this.

header--Metadata
header--data--data---data...so on and so forth

at the target the module should understand that this is a header and should read from the header which data it is recieving.

Can someone help me with something like this?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol and not datagram oriented. You have to add some kind of framing. This does not need to be complicated, for example a 2 byte length field and an additional flags field might be enough in your case. If the length is really always fixed, the length field might not even be necessary.

Comment: You can just make up your own protocol if you're in control of both ends, but it's often easier to use an existing scheme like JSON or HTTP. Perhaps use something like [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)?